# VBA Detail Shortcut Menu

Tags: ms-access, vba, menu, ms-access-2010

I am updating some old VBA code to work with Access 2010. One problem we encountered is that no Shortcut Menu appears when you right click so we create a shortcut menu and bound it to the Application object like so...

```
Application.ShortcutMenuBar = "GeneralClipboardMenu"
```

In general this works however if you right click on a column in a Detail pane, "Which we are using as an excel grid", no menu appears. This aspect is critical to the use of our application so we can not ignore it.

Nowhere in the code are Shortcut Menus being disable. Also I realize shortcut menus are being replaced by the ribbon in the 2010 Office suit however right click is a basic feature that we would ideally like to keep.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code for creating the shortcut menu in-case it is relevant.

```
Sub CreateSimpleShortcutMenu()
  On Error Resume Next 'If menu with same name exists delete
  CommandBars("GeneralClipboardMenu").Delete
  Dim cmb As CommandBar
  Set cmb = CommandBars.Add("GeneralClipboardMenu", msoBarPopup, False, False)
      With cmb
          .Controls.Add msoControlButton, 21, , , True   ' Cut
          .Controls.Add msoControlButton, 19, , , True   ' Copy
          .Controls.Add msoControlButton, 22, , , True   ' Paste
          .Controls.Add msoControlButton, 4016, , , True 'Sort Ascending
          .Controls.Add msoControlButton, 4017, , , True 'Sort Decending
      End With
  Set cmb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Application-wide Shortcut Menu bar is a DAO database property. You can change it in the GUI under Access Options > Current Database > Ribbon and Toolbar Options.

You can also change it using the following code:

```
UpdateCustomProperty("StartupShortcutMenuBar", "NameOfMyCustomShortcutMenuBar")

Private Function CreateCustomProperty(ByVal sPropertyName As String, _
                                        ByVal sPropertyValue As String)
    On Error Resume Next

    If sPropertyName <> "" And sPropertyValue <> "" Then
        Dim p1 As DAO.Property
        Set p1 = CurrentDb.CreateProperty(sPropertyName, DB_TEXT, sPropertyValue)
        CurrentDb.Properties.Append p1
        Set p1 = Nothing
    End If

End Function

Public Function UpdateCustomProperty(ByVal sPropertyName As String, _
                                    ByVal sPropertyValue As String)
    On Error Resume Next

    If sPropertyName <> "" And sPropertyValue <> "" Then
        CurrentDb.Properties(sPropertyName) = sPropertyValue
        If Err.Number = 3270 Then
            Err.Clear
            Call CreateCustomProperty(sPropertyName, sPropertyValue)
        End If
    End If
    Err.Clear
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I discovered a workaround that is satisfactory. The only reason we needed to be able to right click a column was for sorting. Using the code I initially had when you right clicked a cell the sort options where grayed out. However it appears there are several id's for sort commands and they all have different functionality.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/159466

The above link has a list of available id's for shortcut menus.

I am fairly sure there is no way to add right click functionality to entire columns in 2010 detail panes. Nowhere was I disabling menus I did a through search for any commands capable of doing that as well as triple checking my properties.

Comment: What do you mean by a detail pane? A split form? A datasheet view? The detail section on a standard single form?

Comment: I assume that it is a datasheet view but it could very well be a split form. I did not write the code and I can't really tell from my limited knowledge of vba. It has tags as column labels and text boxes as cell if that helps. I really wish this was done in c# with .NET...

Comment: You can capture the right-click event on a datasheet view column by using the Form_Click() event. Do realize that datasheet views are often embedded as subforms within other forms. In that case make sure you use the Form_Click event for the subform, not for the main form. I'm not sure if this will help you or not.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that Shortcut Menu is set to "No" in the form properties.  You can access these by viewing the form in design view, then viewing Form Properties, and checking the "Shortcut Menu" setting.  It should be set to "Yes."